# With make runtime, python modules doen't work

Tags: python, scripting, game-engine, import

I think it is no big problem but, it is really important for me, to do that quickly because I need to have application finished to Friday. I will be really thankful when someone helps me.

My problem is:

I have application made in Blender, which is using python modules in bge.
I have Always actuators linked on controllers of python modules. In that controlers I writed modulename.main for calling function main() in module "modulename". In modules I have functionality of the program.

In blender, when I press "P" all works great.

But when I export application as Runtime. And I copy files like Textures to folder where I save it. It is runeable and scene shows good, but functionality of that game, doesn't work.

I assume, runtime can't find my python modules.

But I was trying many many things, and I don't know, how to fix that.

I saved my python modules in files with .py extension and copy they in folder with runtime. That doesn't help. I copy they to folder with python libraries, and all over runtime tree, but nothing of that doesn't help.

Second I try to "Pack all in .blend file" in File-External (or something like that). With that I doesn't have to copy Texture files into Runtime folder when I save application as Runtime, but python modules still doesn't work.

Highest problem is, I don't know how to debug that. Blender doesn't shows me any errors, and Runtime application doesn't shows me errors too.

I am using Blender 2.73a, and I was trying tu save application as runtime with that version, but when that doesn't work, I try use 2.72 and 2.74 versions. I was trying all that things on Ubuntu 14.10 and Windows 8.
Nothing of that helps me.

I read

[Packaging external libraries in the game engine 'Create Runtime'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6606/packaging-external-libraries-in-the-game-engine-create-runtime)

but that doesn't help me.